# A function $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ that preserves distances must be a linear map followed by a translation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, geometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are isometric normed linear spaces isomorphic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81086/are-isometric-normed-linear-spaces-isomorphic)
>   [$ f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m $ preserving distances](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124510/f-mathbbrn-to-mathbbrm-preserving-distances)

Consider the set of all functions $\varphi : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$
that preserve distance.

That is $\forall a,b : \| a-b\| = \|\varphi(a) - \varphi(b)\| $

Is the following statement true or false?

$\forall \varphi: \exists v \in \mathbb{R}^n, M \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}: \varphi(x) = Mx + v$

Why or why not? (ie rough sketch of proof)

Comment: This is a repeat of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/124510/742)

Comment: And indeed, $M$ must be orthogonal. Presumably the distance is the $2$-norm.

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/36502/5363)