# Extending $f: X\subset \mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ an isometric immersion.

Tags: linear-algebra, real-analysis, metric-spaces

> Let $X\subset \mathbb{R}^m$ not empty and $f: X\to\mathbb{R}^n$ an isometric immersion. Prove that there exists an isometric immersion $\varphi: \mathbb{R}^m \to\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\varphi|_X=f$. When $X$ generates (in the sense of **linear algebra**) $\mathbb{R}^m$, $\varphi$ is unique. Metrics are euclidean metrics (in particular, $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ metrics comes from usual inner product).

**Part of proof:**

> Without loss of generality we can say that $f(0)=0$ (up translations). Then $f$ satisfies $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ and $f(\lambda x)=\lambda f(x) \ \forall \lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ because $f$ preserve distances and the fact that $\mathbb{R}^n$ euclidean metric comes from an **inner product**, is not so hard to prove.

I need to prove the **existence** of $T$ linear transformation such that $T|_X=f$ (assumming $f(0)=0$). I've tried extending $f$ using values of a basis of $X$, but is not factible to prove existence of $T$.

Also, is question possible if $m>n$? or exercise is just incomplete?.

I think that if $X$ generates $\mathbb{R}^m$ the uniqueness is obvious if $T$ is linear extension.

**Added:** I was opened a bounty for +100 because I need to prove existence of $T$. This is the only fact that I can't be formal. If you want to explain what happend if $m>n$ better. But the priority is a formal proof of the fact of existence of $T$.

Comment: "generate" in the sense of linear algebra? Is $f$ supposed to be linear? Upon reading your question, I imagined a piece of paper immersed in $\mathbb{R}^3$ as a cilinder, but I guess this is not at all what you mean by your question?

Comment: @DaanMichiels in the sense of linear algebra. $f$ is not supposed linear. $f$ is given isometric immersion not necesarly coincide with R^2->R^3 cilinder inmersion.

Comment: Indeed, the statement seems to be false when $m>n$: you can immerse a point in $\mathbb R^2$ into $\mathbb R$, but there is no immersion $f\colon \mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$. To prevent misunderstanding, could you define exactly what you mean by *isometric immersion*?

Comment: @LeonidKovalev an isometric inmersion is the same that you think **an injective function such that preserves distances**. Im thinking that we need the fact that $m\leq n$ But my real problem is the proof of existence of function such extend $f$

Comment: If you know the result holds for a subset $S \subset X$ of your domain, it should be possible to construct an extension that holds for your subset plus another point, $S \cup p$, $p \in S \cap X$. Then well-order the points in your domain, and use transfinite induction to prove your result. I will try to write this up in an answer later.

Comment: @NickAlger I didn't understand all, we are in linear algebra atmosphere, adding one point we really are adding many points. If you write an answer later try to explain why given a function $f$ such that $f(0)=0$ and satisfying the same conditions of a LT can be extended to a LT in the whole space. I was tried but I can't be really convinced.

Comment: We are not entirely in linear algebra atmosphere unless $X$ is a linear subspace... Is it a linear subspace? You refer to its *basis* in the post.

Comment: Is a metric subspace. Lineal algebra atmosphere is for we are dealing probably with linear transformations.

Comment: I still don't get the question. What do you mean by $f(0)$? Are you assuming that $0\in X$?

Comment: @DaanMichiels Is an assumption. I think that I didnt loss generality.

Comment: Ewan's answer is a more reasonable approach to the problem than what I wrote above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the OP, we may assume $0\in X$, and $f(0)=0$. The first thing to note is that  $f$ preserves the scalar product, since for any $x,x'$ in $X$ we have

\begin{align*}
\langle f(x),f(x')\rangle&=\frac{d(f(x),0)^2+d(f(x'),0)^2-d(f(x),f(x'))^2}{2}\\
&=\frac{d(x,0)^2+d(x',0)^2-d(x,x')^2}{2}\\
&=\langle x,x'\rangle
\end{align*}

Let $\{y_1,y_2,\dots,y_r\}\subseteq f(X)$ be a basis of $\text{span}(f(X))$. For each $i$ there as an $x_i$ such that $f(x_i)=y_i$. Let us put $H=\text{span}(x_1,x_2, \dots ,x_r)$, and denote by $H^{\perp}$ its orthogonal complement in ${\mathbb R}^m$.
Let $\phi$ be the linear mapping ${\sf span}(f(X)) \to H$, defined by $\phi(y_i)=x_i$. Then $\phi$ preserves scalar products by the equality above, so $\phi$ is an isometry.

Let $x\in X$ and $y=f(x)$. We can decompose $x$ as $x=h+k$, with $h \in H, k \in H^{\perp}$. Then $ \langle  h,k \rangle =0$ , and we have Pythagoras' equality $||x||^2=||h||^2+||k||^2$.
 For any $i$ we have
$$
\langle h,x_i\rangle =\langle x,x_i\rangle =\langle f(x),f(x_i)\rangle =\langle y,y_i\rangle =\langle \phi(y),\phi(y_i)\rangle =\langle \phi(y),x_i\rangle 
$$

So we see that $h$ and $\phi(y)$ are both in $H$ and have equal coordinates in the basis 
$(x_1, \ldots ,x_n)$. So $h=\phi(y)$. Then

$$||h||^2=\langle h,h\rangle =\langle \phi(y),\phi(y)\rangle =\langle y,y\rangle =d(y,0)^2=d(x,0)^2=||x||^2$$

We deduce $||k||^2=||x||^2-||h||^2=0$, so $k=0$, and $x=h=\phi(y)$. Thus $f$ coincides with $\phi^{-1}$ where it is defined, so $f$ is linear and we are done.

Comment: Thanks. You have expanded $f$ isometric inmersion to $\phi^{-1}$ linear application with domain $H=\operatorname{span}(X)$. But, for expanding to whole $\mathbb{R^m}$ what do you do? Expanding $\phi^{-1}$ in $H^{\perp}$ or expanding $\phi$ in $\operatorname{span}(f(X))^{\perp}$?

Comment: Oops sorry have not sense expanding $\phi^{-1}$ to whole $\mathbb{R}^n$. I was full understand now.